# Why does my system not allow me to toggle full-screen using F11?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, 22.04, thinkpad

I'm running Ubuntu 22.04 on a ThinkPad x1 Carbon (gen 7).
Ever since installing Ubuntu I have been unable to toggle full-screen on any tab or window using F-11.

The F-11 key works.

And I can toggle full-screen (in chrome) by navigating over to the drop-down menu.

I have tried every combination of pressing the Fn-lock key together, with Alt-Cntrl-Shift and F-11. Nothing has worked.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use ctrl+ to enable the functioning of the f-keys.